# How Make TreeData to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, tree

I am having a hard time applying the data received from the database to select components.

My database is

| id | code | name | parent_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Marvel |  |
| 2 | 1100 | X-man | Marvel |
| 3 | 1110 | Wolverine | X-man |
| 4 | 1120 | Professor X | X-man |
| 5 | 1200 | Avengers | Marvel |
| 6 | 1210 | Captain America | Avengers |
| 7 | 1211 | Peggy Carter | Captain America |
| 8 | 1220 | Iron Man | Avengers |
| 9 | 1221 | Tony Startk | Iron Man |
| 10 | 1222 | War Machines | Iron Man |
| 11 | 2000 | DC |  |
| 12 | 2100 | BatMan | DC |
| 13 | 2200 | SuperMan | DC |

dbDataArray is here

```
type TreeSelectType = {
  title: string;
  value: string;
  key: string;
  parentName: string | undefined;
  children: TreeSelectType[];
};

const dbDataArray: TreeSelectType[] = [];

dbData.forEach(data => {
    dbDataArray.push({
        "title": data.name,
        "value": data.code,
        "key": data.code,
        "parentName": data.parent_name,
        "children": []
    });
});

console.log(dbDataArray)


[
    {
        "title": "Marvel",
        "value": "1000",
        "key": "1000",
        "parentName": null,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "X-man",
        "value": "1100",
        "key": "1100",
        "parentName": "Marvel",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Wolverine",
        "value": "1110",
        "key": "1110",
        "parentName": "X-man",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Professor X",
        "value": "1120",
        "key": "1120",
        "parentName": "X-man",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Avengers",
        "value": "1200",
        "key": "1200",
        "parentName": "Marvel",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Captain America",
        "value": "1210",
        "key": "1210,
        "parentName": "Avengers",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Peggy Carter",
        "value": "1211",
        "key": "1211",
        "parentName": "Captain America",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Iron Man",
        "value": "1220",
        "key": "1220",
        "parentName": "Avengers",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "Tony Startk",
        "value": "1221",
        "key": "1221",
        "parentName": "Iron Man",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "War Machines",
        "value": "1222",
        "key": "1222",
        "parentName": "Iron Man",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "DC",
        "value": "2000",
        "key": "2000",
        "parentName": null,
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "BatMan",
        "value": "2100",
        "key": "2100",
        "parentName": "DC",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "title": "SuperMan",
        "value": "2200",
        "key": "2200",
        "parentName": "DC",
        "children": []
    },
]
```

I need to treeDataArray. like this.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Marvel",
        "value": "1000",
        "key": "1000",
        "parentName": "Marvel",
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "X-man",
                "value": "1100",
                "key": "1100",
                "parentName": "Marvel",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Wolverine",
                        "value": "1110",
                        "key": "1110",
                        "parentName": "X-man",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Professor X",
                        "value": "1120",
                        "key": "1120",
                        "parentName": "X-man",
                        "children": []
                     },
                 ],
            },
            {
                "title": "Avengers",
                "value": "1200",
                "key": "1200",
                "parentName": "Marvel",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "title": "Captain America",
                        "value": "1210",
                        "key": "1210,
                        "parentName": "Avengers",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "title": "Peggy Carter",
                                "value": "1211",
                                "key": "1211",
                                "parentName": "Captain America",
                                "children": []
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Iron Man",
                        "value": "1220",
                        "key": "1220",
                        "parentName": "Avengers",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "title": "Tony Startk",
                                "value": "1221",
                                "key": "1221",
                                "parentName": "Iron Man",
                                "children": []
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "War Machines",
                                "value": "1222",
                                "key": "1222",
                                "parentName": "Iron Man",
                                "children": []
                            },
                        ]    
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "DC",
        "value": "2000",
        "key": "2000",
        "parentName": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "title": "BatMan",
                "value": "2100",
                "key": "2100",
                "parentName": "DC",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "title": "SuperMan",
                "value": "2200",
                "key": "2200",
                "parentName": "DC",
                "children": []
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

How Can I... please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Map` keyed by `title` and with the corresponding objects as values. Then use that map to retrieve for each object the parent object, and insert it in the parent's `children` array.

Here is how that could look:

```js
const dbDataArray = [{"title": "Marvel","value": "1000","key": "1000","parentName": null,"children": []},{"title": "X-man","value": "1100","key": "1100","parentName": "Marvel","children": []},{"title": "Wolverine","value": "1110","key": "1110","parentName": "X-man","children": []},{"title": "Professor X","value": "1120","key": "1120","parentName": "X-man","children": []},{"title": "Avengers","value": "1200","key": "1200","parentName": "Marvel","children": []},{"title": "Captain America","value": "1210","key": "1210","parentName": "Avengers","children": []},{"title": "Peggy Carter","value": "1211","key": "1211","parentName": "Captain America","children": []},{"title": "Iron Man","value": "1220","key": "1220","parentName": "Avengers","children": []},{"title": "Tony Startk","value": "1221","key": "1221","parentName": "Iron Man","children": []},{"title": "War Machines","value": "1222","key": "1222","parentName": "Iron Man","children": []},{"title": "DC","value": "2000","key": "2000","parentName": null,"children": []},{"title": "BatMan","value": "2100","key": "2100","parentName": "DC","children": []},{"title": "SuperMan","value": "2200","key": "2200","parentName": "DC","children": []},]

const result = [];
const map = new Map(dbDataArray.map(o => [o.title, o])).set(null, {children: result});
for (const o of dbDataArray) map.get(o.parentName).children.push(o);
console.log(result);
```